# When should I use recycling = true with IFeatureClass.Update?

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-10.1

I am migrating .NET code from 9.3 to 10.1
The code is using
IFeatureClass.Update(queryfileter, true) where true is for recycling.

I know recycling should not be used when we do update, and actually it was permitted on 9.3 in spite of being undesirable, and it is totally prevented on 10.1

On 10.1 I did changed it to false.
But I got another issue.

but first let me ask my first question. If it is not permitted , then why you give it as an option in 10.1 when we open an update cursor?

Is it possible to use it in 10.1 with recycle being true? (and I am getting an error that you cannot update recyclable cursor).

and my second question.
After I changed it to false I got a different issue
I was able to successfully update the features.
It worked for all kind of update.
But it is hanging on one place, where I am selecting more that 100,000 rows at once.

The IFeatureClass.Update is hanging, without doing anything.
I put logging everywhere in the code, and it hangs exactly where I am submitting the select.

I want to ask if any one has any idea on how to do what I am doing on 10.1

P.S, I am maintaining very bad written and messy code, and what I need is just to migrate it to 10.1 with the less modification possible.

Thanks

Comment: Does it totally freeze? or just take an inordinately long time on the IFeatureClass.Update?

Comment: it freezes without any error or exception. even I left it and come the next day, and still it was stuck on the same point.
I updated the question to explain more.